# How to make my android application interact with the interface of other applications?

Tags: user-interface, pyautogui

I need to make an android app that will open on the top of all windows and interact with other applications, but I do not understand how to implement this, since I had little to do with the development of native android applications. I need something like pywinauto or pyautogui, just an android. At the same time, the language is not important, since I am a little familiar with android studio, but my attempts to find at least an approximate guide about how to create something like a car clicker for android, were unsuccessful. Maybe someone knows the articles, or guides about how such "automation" is being implemented for android.

The python + appium junction is not suitable for me, because at the output you need not a script, but an application that automates certain actions.